# Is there a way to direct serverless to put functions under a pre-existing API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm building a serverless application.

My ops team has some restrictions that are best resolved by me using a pre-existing (but currently empty) API gateway.

Is there a way to tell serverless to use this gateway instead of creating its own?

Comment: Do you mean you serverless framework to re-use your existing API Gateway API for your Lambda functions instead of a new API?

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless framework does provide the ability to re-use a pre-existing API in their latest update.
 You can refer https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources

for details.
Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create the Lambda without any event-configuration in the `serverless.yml`, and then manually configure the existing API Gateway to trigger the created lambda. I think it is a fairly good solution in your case, since the API Gateway is configured somewhere else anyway.

Comment: That pretty much defeats the whole purpose of the serverless framework